# Is there a Nikon F to Sony E/FE lens adapter?

Tags: nikon, sony, lens-adapter

I had a good entry-level Nikon DSLR. I still have the lens(es). I bought a Sony mirrorless interchangeable lens camera (NEX?). Is there an adapter to connect the Nikon lenses to the Sony camera?

Comment: It *is* a bit rough around the edges as it is (a bad machine translation from Russian). I can read it, though, with a little difficulty, so I'm editing. (It will probably be a duplicate. My search-fu isn't great.)

Comment: @StanRogers - Thanks for the update, I've reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is:

http://srb-photographic.co.uk/sony-nex-to-nikon-g-digital-and-manual-lens-adaptor-3365-p.asp

This is a British site but I'm sure they ship overseas.